# VS2008: Snippet shown in code snippet manager but doesn't exist in editor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

According to the Code Snippet Manager in Visual Studio 2008 there is a code snippet named "wpfre" which expands to a routed event registration. However, when I try to enter it into the text editor, Intellisense won't complete to it and if I type "wpfre" and hit TAB it just completes to "wde" which is not the right thing.

I googled for it, but found nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "wpfre" snippet is for "Visual Basic".

Are you searching for this snippet in a C# project ?

I am able to see this snippet in my Visual Studio 2008 (Tools->Code Snippet Manager). This is listed under "Visual Basic" language, under "WPF" folder

("Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Vb\Snippets\1033\WPF\RoutedEvent.snippet")